# Who is "Yasmine Tazi" in Return to Monkey Island?

Tags: return-to-monkey-island

In the recent sequel *Return to Monkey Island*, the end credits for the voice actors include a mention of a character "Yasmine Tazi", voiced by Sara Amini.

In playing the game, I met no such character, and can't find anything in a Web search either (though a few walkthroughs have been posted by now). So who is this character? Was she cut from the game?

Comment: wouldn't be surprised if she was the skeleton lady in the trailer...

Answer (score 6):

Found her! At least I think I have.

[image: She's the one on the right]

She's the dark-skinned pirate outside the destroyed Scumm Bar in chapter 5.

In game, the character never tells Guybrush her name so she is only ever referred to as "Pirate" in the subtitles. There is no character listed as "pirate" (except the Quarantined Pirates who this is obviously not).

I did a bit of research and the voice does sound like her, or at least like her doing an accent.

What seems to have happened is the character was given a name during the writing process but didn't get any lines to reveal her name.

Comment: Aha, it's possible. I played the game with voices turned off, and assumed that character was male, from the appearance!

Comment: @equin0x80 My Obra Dinn skills at work. I'll put dehydration as cause of death because Guybrush never let her finish her drink.

Comment: It is the same pirate who is closest to the door inside the SCUMM bar.